# How to select top 100 features(a subset) which are most relevant after pca?

Tags: matlab, data-mining

I performed PCA on a 63*2308 matrix and obtained a score and a co-efficient matrix. The score matrix is 63*2308 and the co-efficient matrix is 2308*2308 in dimensions.

How do i extract the column names for the top 100 features which are most important so that i can perform regression on them?

Comment: could you show a short study case of what you wanna perform? this would make your question clearer.

Comment: I have a gene dataset comprising of 2308 genes for 63 patients. Im performing PCA for reducing the dimensions. After reducing the dimensions I want to select the top 100 features to perform logistic regression on it. Does that make sense?

Comment: I tried giving an answer, if I got the meaning of `top features` properly.

Comment: The top features are those features(column) which have a high variance of data

Answer (score 4):

PCA should give you both a set of eigenvectors (your co-efficient matrix) and a vector of eigenvalues (1*2308) often referred to as lambda). You might been to use a different PCA function in matlab to get them.

The eigenvalues indicate how much of your data each eigenvector explains. A simple method for selecting features would be to select the 100 features with the highest eigen values. This gives you a set of feature which explain most of the variance in the data.

If you need to justify your approach for a write up you can actually calculate the amount of variance explained per eigenvector and cut of at, for example, 95% variance explained.

Bear in mind that selecting based solely on eigenvalue, might not correspond to the set of features most important to your regression, so if you don't get the performance you expect you might want to try a different feature selection method such as recursive feature selection. I would suggest using google scholar to find a couple of papers doing something similar and see what methods they use.

---

A quick matlab example of taking the top 100 principle components using PCA.

```
[eigenvectors, projected_data, eigenvalues] = princomp(X);
[foo, feature_idx] = sort(eigenvalues, 'descend');
selected_projected_data = projected(:, feature_idx(1:100));
```

Comment: I have got the eigen values. Is there a way to find what columns in the original data these eigen values correspond to? It would help select the columns out of the 2308 features and perform regression on the data.

Comment: When doing PCA you transform your data so that you are no longer working with the original features, but new features made up by combining them. When you do the feature selection you select from these new features. While it is possible to map back from the new features to the old features using the eigenvectors, doing so is non-trivial and - unless you have a different reason for doing so - it's probably not what you want to do. I have modified my answer to include some sample matlab code for selecting the top 100 projeted features for regression, incase that is what you were after.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with

```
B = sort(your_matrix,2,'descend');
C = B(:,1:100);
```

Comment: What does your_matrix represent? Is it referring to the score matrix?

Comment: I have another question. The variable C would retrieve a 100 dimensions. Is there a way to know what these 100 dimensions exactly are? I sorted the score matrix using B = sort(score,2,'descend') and then used C = B(:,1:100) which gives me top 100 column based on the scores. How will I choose 100 dimensions from original matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Be careful!

With just 63 observations and 2308 variables, your PCA result will be meaningless because the data is **underspecified**. You should have at least (rule of thumb) dimensions*3 observations.

With 63 observations, you can at most define a 62 dimensional hyperspace!