# How to select top needed features(variables) after pca in matlab?

Tags: matlab, correlation, pca

I have referred [How to select top 100 features(a subset) which are most relevant after pca?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15865340/how-to-select-top-100-featuresa-subset-which-are-most-relevant-after-pca)

I am using pca() instead of princomp() as it is removed in new release.

I know that "The eigenvalues indicate how much of your data each eigenvector explains. A simple method for selecting features would be to select the 100 features with the highest eigen values".

For example , if I run the following in matlab

```
 [coeff,score,latent] = pca(pcaInput);
```

then latent give me the values I need.

But , the latent is given in sorted order.How do I know , the first value of vector latent corresponding to which variable in my data set ?

Comment: The values in the `latent` vector correspond to the columns of the `coeff` matrix. The most important principal component would be the first column, with the rest following in decreasing order. PCA changes the coordinate system, giving you a new set of variables to work with. The original variables in your dataset no longer have any meaning.

Comment: It would also be good for future readers if you stated which version you are using...

Comment: @eigenchris I am using pca for feature selection only , I want the pca to give me top k variable list so that I can give that variables as input to some another module.

Comment: @user2670535 The new feature axes are the columns of the `coeffs` matrix. I don't understand what the problem is?

Comment: @eigenchris the output of pca gives the "transformed" features , I need the original data columns. like if given 100 variables data set and I want to "select" top 10 correlated  variables.

Comment: @user2670535 have you found the solution? I'm looking for it too.

Answer (score 0):

In the docs:

> The columns are in order of decreasing component variance.

Generally the eigenvectors from PCA are ordered from most relevant to less, its a non-written "standard" AFAIK.

Plus the first value of `latent` corresponds to the first row of the eigenvector of course, there is no reordering needed.